# how does "str_getcsv" works and what is alternative?

Tags: javascript, php, json, csv

i'm converting csv file into json so i can use it in javascript. 
how i'm still new to php programing I google the ways to do that and i find following code to do it:

```
 $csv= file_get_contents($file);
 $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
 json_encode($array);

?>
```

but does "str_getcsv" turns my array into string? so does that mean that i can't use values from that array later in javascript to manipulate them?
what is the alternative?
thx in advance

Comment: See the manual on [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv); it splits lines on (mostly) commas into arrays. -- Also [`file()`](http://php.net/file) is preferrable over the file_get_contents+explode workaround.

Comment: You could use a client-side javascript library to do the parsing. If you're not considering this, please remove the `javascript` tag from your question.

Comment: if you've got a file already, why not `fgetcsv()`?

Comment: Converting it to a string is probably easier to understand, but it's definitely better from a performance angle to use filestream operations. Maintaining one array instead of potentially two large arrays can prevent a lot of nasty problems. I just had to rewrite such a script not long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_getcsv` transforms your csv line (a string) into an array (read the doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

What that script does is:

- `$csv= file_get_contents($file);` put the content of the file inside the variable `$csv`
- `$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));` will break the string into an array of strings separated at every new line (`explode("\n", $csv)`) and then will call the function `str_getcsv` for each array element
- `json_encode($array);` will return the array as a json string

So you should add an `echo` to have your string in the output so you can use it as a javascript object. Something like

```
<script>
    var json = <?php echo json_encode($array);?>
</script>
```

The point in doing so is that `str_getcsv` doesn't parse the full csv but just one line. That script goes through every line in a nice compact way.
Another way to do it would be opening a file handler and using the function [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Answer (score 0):

The function [`str_getcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) as per documentation:

```
Parses a string input for fields in CSV format and returns an array
containing the fields read.
```

You should note that PHP isn't very well optimized for this sort of operation. If you're reading in large files, you should at least look at using [`fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead to cut down on memory usage.